# Использование useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Как правильно использовать useEffect чтобы он сработал **только** при первом появлении компонента. То есть фактически componentDidMount но с использованием хука эффекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте такой вариант

```
useEffect(() => {
     console.log("это componentDidMount")
     return () => console.log("это componentWillUnmount")
}, [])
```

в качестве `deps` используйте пустой массив

Comment: на пустой [deps] ругается es-lint